# R to xlsx: conditional styling of column based on content of other column

Tags: r, styling, xlconnect

I want open an existing xlsx file and write data to a tab as follows:

```
require(XLConnect)
df <- mtcars

wb <- loadWorkbook("myExcel.xlsx")

writeWorksheet(wb, df, sheet= "Tab1" )

saveWorkbook ( wb, "myNewExcel.xlsx")
```

But let's say I would like to do conditional styling on the mpg column in the xlsx file based on the content of the gear column. Say I want to give data that has df$gear == 4 a green cell in the mpg column, df$gear == 3 a yellow cell, and leave the rest unchanged. How do I would I accomplish that through (preferably) the XLConnect package?

Comment: Can't you set excel conditional formatting in advance?

Comment: Thought of that, but this is a simplified version of the problem I run into which cannot be solved by formatting in advance unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe you can create a VBA script and run it to set the formatting

Comment: Another option is following the example on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf topic 6.2

Comment: Combine it with this page https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/07/07/custom-excel-number-format/ section Apply custom number formats based on conditions

Comment: As I mentioned, this question is a simplified version of a more complex issue. I am constantly generating new tabs in R in which different tables will be printed. It will be impossible to manually add these conditions to every new tab. Also, I would like to delete (in this case) gear column after the mpg column has been formatted. So doing everything in R would be very much preferred.

Comment: I think you have landed on VBA land, I honestly can't imagine an interface language (either R or Python) being capable of implementing what you are describing